# How to make shorter if statement in React

Tags: reactjs

I have minor problem in React.I made game where you have to memorize colors,click on them and if they match you move to the next level.I've tried many options only one work.I wan't to make this condition shorter.Here is the code:

```
             if(all[0].style.background===red && 
                all[25].style.background===red && 
                all[29].style.background===red) {

               //make this shorter

              }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if([0, 25, 29].every(index => all[index] === red)) {

}
```